# File corrupted after upload to FTP server with WebRequest

Tags: c#, ftp, webrequest, ftpwebrequest

Here's some problem with transporting .csv file to FTP server. Before transfering it's okay, but when i'm checking it on FTP it looks like broken or something:

```
"ЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ  T8пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ\p3>@L @E8?5=:>                                                                               BпїЅaпїЅ="
```

Is it problem with encoding? I'm using this method of download:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://xxxxxxxx.xx/" + name);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "qweqwe123");
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("F:\\" + xxxx);

        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't like to answer under my aquestions, but it's too long for comment:
Solved, maybe somebody have this problem. Try to use this upload method:

```
FileInfo toUpload = new FileInfo("log.txt");
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://csharpcoderr.com/public_html/" + toUpload.Name);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name", "pass");
Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("log.txt");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;
do
{
   bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
   ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
while (bytesRead != 0);
fileStream.Close();
ftpStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can across this question with the same issue.
Expanding on Brawl_Ups solution...
And it seems that its best to use the BinaryReader for binary files.
This is a snippet I eventfully came up with...
This is a current work in progress and any edits are welcome.

```
public string UploadFile()
{
    string sRetVal = string.Empty;
    string sFullDestination = this.DestinatinFullIDPath + this.UpLoadFileName;
    try
    {
        if ((this.CreateDestinationDir(this.DestinatinFullModulePath) == true) &
            (this.CreateDestinationDir(this.DestinatinFullIDPath) == true))
        {

            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sFullDestination);
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.UserName, this.Password);
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = false;

            byte[] fileContents;
            using (BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(this.UpLoadFullName)))
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(this.UpLoadFullName);
                binReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                fileContents = binReader.ReadBytes((int)fi.Length);
            }

            ftpRequest.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            using (Stream requestStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            }

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                sRetVal = string.Format("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception((ex.Response as FtpWebResponse).StatusDescription);
    }
    return sRetVal;
}
```